# Using classes from other modules

Tags: c#, entity-framework, inheritance, architecture

I am working in a project that has several modules made by different teams.

I must use the repositories and the code-first entity classes from other modules (referencing the dll), but I can't access the code and I can't modify it.

I want to protect myself from changes in the structure of the external code, and I want to add functionality to those classes.

What is the best approach?

I am thinking about making something like a service layer; get the external data, adding some functionality and parse to my own classes to avoid extra dependence on the external assemblies in my code.

If some day the external classes change, I only need to modify this service layer.

What do you think? Other ways for doing it? I can only change my module.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No matter what, you will always have a dependency on the entity classes. If you create a wrapper layer and translate the external types to internal types (that you own), then your wrapper layer needs to be updated when the external types change. If you don't create a wrapper layer, then your business logic will need to be adapted instead. The question is, how frequently do you expect changes, how big will those changes be (adding classes and properties usually doesn't cause issues, renaming/restructing/removing does)? Then trade off between work now or later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot come up with a sophisticated method that could better fit the situation but what you need is some kind of abstraction. You could create a wrapper object or this could be as simple as following:

```
public class MyType
{
    // Your own implementation
    // Properties
    // And methods

    public static MyType Create(TheirEntity entity)
    {
        // Create an instance of your type from their object
    }

    // Or provide a conversion operator, it could be implicit if you'd like
    public static explicit MyType(TheirEntity entity)
    {
         // Implement a conversion here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The teams must work together!

It is a good idea to work against interfaces instead of concrete classes. Classes should implement different interfaces representing their different facets. Maybe the classes themselves can be split into smaller ones having only one responsibility.

See: [Interface segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).
See: [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

If you are using only a portion of an object, there is no point in making you dependent on the whole object. If you work against an interface representing the very aspects of the class you are working with, it is less likely that changes on other parts will affect you. But the teams must sit together and define those interfaces.

Comment: This is the ideal answer, but it's imposible.

Comment: This is the ideal answer, but it's hard to coordinate us. Old code, use of cases with requent changes, international developers teams of different companies...  It's a lost battle. I prefer build a wrapper layer for protect me from changes and add my own methods. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use repositories from external libraries, why don't you inherit from the classes you want to extend? If you don't need to add properties or fields, I'd use extension methods. Those would allow you to use your project specific functionality on external classes.